# MethodNotAllowed when trying to do an update.

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'm using PHPstorm with Laravel 5.2.3, and currently trying to update a persons information by reusing a form from my create page. I've followed everything to the T from the laracast tutorials, but for some reason I'm getting the `MethodNotAllowed` error when I hit submit on an update.

**Routes**

```html
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function()
{
    ...

    Route::get('create','ResourceController@create');

    Route::post('create', 'ResourceController@store');

    Route::resource('pages', 'ResourceController');
});
```

**Controller**

```html
class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    public function store(Requests\CreateNewContactRequest $request)
    {
        ContactPerson::create($request->all());

        return redirect('resource');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
       $user = ContactPerson::findOrFail($id);

       return view('pages.edit')->with(compact('user'));
    }

    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $user = ContactPerson::findOrFail($id);

        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect('pages.resource');
    }
}
```

**Edit View**

```html
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ResourceController@update', $user->id]]) !!}

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('first', 'First Name: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('First_Name', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('last', 'Last Name: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('Last_Name', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>
    
      ...
    
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**View Source**

It shows that it's a POST method with laravel spoofing it as a PATCH. 
[image: view page source]

**Error**
[image: error]

Comment: Ok, so I got it to where I can edit the information, and hit submit without an error. `{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['pages.update', $user->id]]) !!}` It's creating a new record in the database with the existing information along with the edits though, so it seems like maybe it's doing a PUT instead of a PATCH, or when it's just not even bothering to update and just creating instead.

Answer (score 1):

It generates wrong action in `<form>` tag. Try using:

```
'route' => ['pages.update', $user->id]
```

instead of:

```
'action' => ['ResourceController@update', $user->id]
```

Is it works?.

Comment: or try

{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['pages.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}

Comment: No, both solutions still throw the `MethodNotAllowed` error. This is very weird, because I followed along with the tutorial, and typed everything he typed.

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` to see all routes.